# Format SQL query to accept list of quoted values

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-injection

I'm trying to delete a list of accounts from a table using the python3 sqlite3 API.

The query should be like this:

```sql
DELETE FROM table WHERE email in ("email1", "email2", "email3")
```

```py
delete_list = [f'"{email}"' for email in emails]
query = f"DELETE FROM {table} WHERE email IN (" + ", ".join(delete_list) + ")"
        
try:
    self.cursor.execute(query)
    self.connection.commit()
    return True
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    self.connection.rollback()
    return False
```

This code works but is obviously vulnerable to SQL injections. Is there a safer way to build my SQL query using sqlite3 ?

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly.

```py
query = f"DELETE FROM {table} WHERE email IN (" + ", ".join("?" * len(emails)) + ")"

try:
    self.cursor.execute(query, emails)
    self.connection.commit()
    ...
```